# Posible to obtain history ledger(balance) with sql query?

Tags: postgresql

Not sure if this is the place to ask but here it goes. I am using a Postgres server and to make things simpler, I'll try to show a brief scenario of what I need.

```
CREATE TABLE operations(id,type,item,price,amount)
 AS VALUES
  ( 1::int, 'buy' , 'item1',  2, 10::int ),
  ( 2::int, 'buy' , 'item1',  3,  4::int ),
  ( 3::int, 'sell', 'item1',  4, 12::int )
;
```

- If I go through a FIFO cost basis the ledger or balances after each order should look like:

  ```
  id  |  price   | amount |

  1   |      2   |     10 |

  2   |      2   |     10 |
      |      3   |      4 |

  3   |      3   |      2 |
  ```

One thing that I've tried is to have a table like operation_balances in which for each processed operation I insert the corresponding balance. This works however there's a problem with the huge amount of balances that get inserted for large number of operations so it's not a valid solution. I was wondering if it's possible to obtain the balance part for each order as part of a sql query. It may take a little while to run but it would save a lot of database space.

Comment: What exactly makes `operation_balances` not valid; specifically, is this a problem with incorrect data, performance, or something else? What do you use the balance for each order for? How quickly would this query have to run to be considered "valid"? I think we'll need a bit more detail to be able to help you.

Comment: @RDFozz I think you're being a bit hard on him, expressing this in SQL is pretty complex, I'm not even sure if I would use a window function or a cursor to do this. It's a really good question. I'm totally confused at why you need this, but it's a good question.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - It's not that I think it's a bad question - just one that will require a bit more detail to give a really good answer (and to confirm that it's not an X-Y problem). There are those cases where providing a simple answer to the question can actually do the OP a *dis*service.

Comment: Well to answer your question, I think he just wants it to be calculated at runtime, and to eliminate the cache table "saves a lot of database space" I don't think there is a simple answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, and this is just to get you somewhere,

```
SELECT *,
  jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('p',price,'a',amount))
    FILTER (WHERE type='buy')
    OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY id)
    AS cumpurchased
FROM operations;
 id | type | item  | price | amount |             cumpurchased              
----+------+-------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------
  1 | buy  | item1 |     2 |     10 | [{"a": 10, "p": 2}]
  2 | buy  | item1 |     3 |      4 | [{"a": 10, "p": 2}, {"a": 4, "p": 3}]
  3 | sell | item1 |     4 |     12 | [{"a": 10, "p": 2}, {"a": 4, "p": 3}]
```

Here, we serialize the purchases into `cumpurchased`. This seems simple, now we can blow this up by expanding `cumpurchased` to the individual transactions.

```
SELECT id, type, item, price, amount, cumsale, e, eid
FROM (
        SELECT *,
                sum(amount) FILTER (WHERE type='sell') OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cumsale,
        jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('p',price,'a',amount))
                        FILTER (WHERE type='buy')
        OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY id)
        AS cumpurchased
        FROM operations
) AS with_agg
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(cumpurchased)
        WITH ORDINALITY
        AS jsonb(e,eid)
ORDER BY id, eid;
 id | type | item  | price | amount | cumsale |         e         | eid 
----+------+-------+-------+--------+---------+-------------------+-----
  1 | buy  | item1 |     2 |     10 |         | {"a": 10, "p": 2} |   1
  2 | buy  | item1 |     3 |      4 |         | {"a": 10, "p": 2} |   1
  2 | buy  | item1 |     3 |      4 |         | {"a": 4, "p": 3}  |   2
  3 | sell | item1 |     4 |     12 |      12 | {"a": 10, "p": 2} |   1
  3 | sell | item1 |     4 |     12 |      12 | {"a": 4, "p": 3}  |   2
(5 rows)
```

You should be ale to see where I'm going with this...

```
SELECT id,type,item,e,eid,sum(
        (e->>'a')::int
) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY eid)
        - coalesce(cumsale,0)
  AS qty_remaining
FROM (
        SELECT *,
                sum(amount) FILTER (WHERE type='sell') OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cumsale,
        jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('p',price,'a',amount))
                        FILTER (WHERE type='buy')
        OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY id)
        AS cumpurchased
        FROM operations
) AS with_agg
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(cumpurchased)
        WITH ORDINALITY
        AS jsonb(e,eid);
 id | type | item  |         e         | eid | qty_remaining 
----+------+-------+-------------------+-----+---------------
  1 | buy  | item1 | {"a": 10, "p": 2} |   1 |            10
  2 | buy  | item1 | {"a": 10, "p": 2} |   1 |            10
  2 | buy  | item1 | {"a": 4, "p": 3}  |   2 |            14
  3 | sell | item1 | {"a": 10, "p": 2} |   1 |            -2
  3 | sell | item1 | {"a": 4, "p": 3}  |   2 |             2
(5 rows)
```

From this point, you need to filter out the -2, we wrap the query again and put that conditional in there. Then we just select from that.

```
SELECT id, e->>'p' AS price, least(qty_remaining,(e->>'a')::int) AS amount
FROM (
      SELECT id,type,item,e,eid,sum(
        (e->>'a')::int
      ) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY eid)
        - coalesce(cumsale,0)
        AS qty_remaining
      FROM (
        SELECT *,
          sum(amount) FILTER (WHERE type='sell') OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cumsale,
          jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('p',price,'a',amount))
            FILTER (WHERE type='buy')
            OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY id)
            AS cumpurchased
        FROM operations
      ) AS with_agg
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(cumpurchased)
        WITH ORDINALITY
        AS jsonb(e,eid)
      ) AS t
WHERE qty_remaining > 0;
 id | price | amount 
----+-------+--------
  1 | 2     |     10
  2 | 2     |     10
  2 | 3     |      4
  3 | 3     |      2
(4 rows)
```

Comment: This is a really amazing and unexpected answer which I need to deeply investigate and learn from it. Thank you very much for all the time you took to write such a detailed answer.